# Using JQuery to check if no radio button in a group has been checked

Tags: jquery

I'm sitting with a problem, I need to check with JQuery if no radio button within a radio button group has been checked, so that I can give the users an javascript error if they forgot to check a option.

I'm using the following code to get the values

```
var radio_button_val = $("input[name='html_elements']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
if (!$("input[name='html_elements']:checked").val()) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the checked radio button has a value=""

Comment: @ScottE - excellent point - I'll remove this answer if Roland unaccepts it.

Comment: I think you could just change it to `.val() == ""` and remove the `!` and you would be all set.

Comment: @Doug - wouldn't that still have the problem ScottE mentioned? What would `.val()` return if the checked radio button had `value=""`? (Though I suppose you could argue that's a fairly unlikely case).

Comment: Sorry, my comment was confusing: I meant for the whole test to look like this: `if ($("input[name='html_elements']:checked").val() == "")` Which would alert "Nothing is checked"

Comment: Damn, I had to log in to downvote this bad answer: it will fail if the value of the radio is 0 (zero) or empty string, or null...

Comment: Its just the perfect solution.

Answer (score 154):

I'm using

```
$("input:radio[name='html_radio']").is(":checked")
```

And will return FALSE if all the items in the radiogroup are unchecked and TRUE if an item is checked.

Comment: This answer worked for me reliably to check whether a radio button group had a selected value. Best answer in the thread.

Comment: Both the answer by Dominic Rodger and Jacobo Hernández work well. I personally try to never use the leading NOT (!) at the beginning of the line. Years later it gets hard to debug when you overlook that and have the logic backwards... is(":checked") is very clear what you are doing - Best answer.

Answer (score 32):

You could do something like this:

```
var radio_buttons = $("input[name='html_elements']");
if( radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0){
  // None checked
} else {
  // If you need to use the result you can do so without
  // another (costly) jQuery selector call:
  var val = radio_buttons.val();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you narrow the first two lines down to just `if ($("input[name='html_elements']:checked").length == 0){` ?

Comment: You could, but then you would need another full jQuery selection to get the value if you showed a value existed.

Answer (score 6):

```
if ($("input[name='html_elements']:checked").size()==0) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `.length` refer to http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
if ($('input[name="html_elements"]:checked').length === 0) alert("Not checked");
else alert("Checked");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var len = $('#your_form_id input:radio:checked').length;
      if (!len) {
        alert("None checked");
      };
      alert("checked: "+ len);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a simple example, how to check if a radio in a group of radios was checked.

```
if($('input[name=html_elements]:checked').length){
    //a radio button was checked
}else{
    //there was no radio button checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this much simple

HTML

```
<label class="radio"><input id="job1" type="radio" name="job" value="1" checked>New Job</label>
<label class="radio"><input id="job2" type="radio" name="job" value="2">Updating Job</label>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="save();">Save</button>
```

SCRIPT

```
 $('#save').on('click', function(e) {
    if (job1.checked)
        {
              alert("New Job"); 
        }
if (job2.checked)
        {
            alert("Updating Job");
        }
```

}