# Validate a form to ensure atleast one radio button is checked in a group

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am making a form with radio buttons in it. I am able to validate all other input except radio button. I got a accepted solution for this in this site

[Using JQuery to check if no radio button in a group has been checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072249/using-jquery-to-check-if-no-radio-button-in-a-group-has-been-checked)

but this is not working for me

http://jsfiddle.net/ghan_123/trr185L2/2/

my code

```
<input type='radio' name='datetime' value='1'>1
<input type='radio' name='datetime' value='2'>2
<input type='radio' name='datetime' value='3'>3
<input type='radio' name='datetime' value='4'>4
<input type='radio' name='datetime' value='5'>5
<br><button id='buttonnew'>validate</button>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonnew").click(function(){

        var selection=document.querySelector('input[name="datetime"]:checked').value;
    // my method    
if(selection=='')
        {
            alert('please select a value');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('your selected value is '+selection);
        }
// end my method

        //  other method ( given in this site link above) 

  if (!$("input[name='datetime']:checked").val()) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}    
       // end other method   



    });
});
```

when nothing is checked no alert message appears.
else both give alert message on select one of these.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998083/jquery-validation-check-for-radio-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was you were trying to get `value` of radio button when none was `checked` and it used to you error on `console`. So first you need to check whether anything is `checked` and if yes then assign the value else assign empty value as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/trr185L2/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonnew").click(function(){
        var selection=document.querySelector('input[name="datetime"]:checked')!=null?
                      document.querySelector('input[name="datetime"]:checked').value:"";
        //Conditional operator
       if(selection!='')
        {
            alert('your selected value is '+selection);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('please select a time slot');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I think you want something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonnew").click(function(){

        var chek=document.querySelector('input[name="datetime"]:checked');
        if(chek!=null){
        var selection=document.querySelector('input[name="datetime"]:checked').value;
        console.log(selection);
    // my method    
if(selection=='')
        {
            alert('please select a time slot');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('your selected value is '+selection);
        }
        }
// end my mehod

        //  other method  
  if (!$("input[name='datetime']:checked").val()) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}      
       // end other method   



    });
});
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ghan_123/trr185L2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this solution :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#buttonnew").click(function () {
    // variable for increament value
    var inc = 0;
    // loop over all of radio button
    $('[name="datetime"]').each(function () {
        // if any of radio button was checked
        // then increase inc variable to one value
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) inc++;
    });
    // if variable stay with 0 value
    // so, we know that no radio button was clicked
    if (inc == 0) {
        alert('Please check one');
        return;
    }

    // continue your another action
 });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/trr185L2/5/)**