# Radio boxes won't validate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a series of radio groups, all with the same name because they are dynamically generated. I want them to be required, but nothing I'm doing is making that happen (including trying to count checked items with jquery).

I'm guessing this is due to some sort of ID conflict?

I have the radios marked as "required" in the HTML.

Or could this be due to the way I'm processing with jquery?

```
<div class="benchmark-question-title"><?php echo $atts['content']; ?></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <form class="benchmark-question-binary">
                               <label class="benchmark-yes-no"><input type="radio" name="yesno"  value="yes" required>Yes</label>
                               <label class="benchmark-yes-no"><input type="radio" name="yesno" value="no" checked required>No</label>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <span class="benchmark-move-forward italic">If yes, move on to the next movement</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

When I attempt to see if any radio groups with name "yesno" are NOT checked with jquery, it doesn't appear to recognize the groups and counts every option individually.

```
$('input:radio[name=yesno]').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(":checked") ){
        console.log('checked')
    }
    else{
        console.log('not checked');
    }
});
```

```js
$('input:radio[name=yesno]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    console.log('checked')
  } else {
    console.log('not checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="benchmark-question-title">
  <?php echo $atts['content']; ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form class="benchmark-question-binary">
      <label class="benchmark-yes-no"><input type="radio" name="yesno"  value="yes" required>Yes</label>
      <label class="benchmark-yes-no"><input type="radio" name="yesno" value="no" checked required>No</label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <span class="benchmark-move-forward italic">If yes, move on to the next movement</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a matter of ids since you are not using the id attribute in the code you have provided. The point could be that your js code is in the document.ready function but you say you are adding these items dinamically. So you have to use deferred objects to handle items that are added to the dom after the page has rendered

Comment: is this all your html code?

Comment: Got it!

'
    $('.benchmark-question').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0)
          {
             console.log("checked");
          }
        else
          {
             console.log("not checked");
             fail = true;
          }
'

Answer (score 0):

no need to itterate through, just check the checked state of the group.

```
$("input:radio[name='yesno']").is(":checked")
```

or

```
$("input:radio[name='yesno']:checked").val()
```

[Using JQuery to check if no radio button in a group has been checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072249/using-jquery-to-check-if-no-radio-button-in-a-group-has-been-checked)

Comment: Brilliant! I was thinking because there were multiple groups, even with the same name, I needed to iterate through. Thanks boss.

Comment: My initial test tricked me. If ANY radio group of the same name has been checked off, the above statement returns true. Even if some of them are unchecked. That's why I was iterating through originally- if they ALL returned true, then I would be in good shape.

Comment: make sure to accept if this answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following what exactly you're trying to accomplish, however if you're looking for the default functionality of only being able to select one radio at a time, you just need to add brackets to the name. Doing this, you also won't have to do any validation if you mark one of the radios as default (as they can't be deselected).

```
<input type="radio" name="yesno[]" value="yes" />
<input type="radio" name="yesno[]" value="no" checked />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form to base an event on. Here I used both the change and a validate event - so you can trigger the validate whenever you wish (like on a form submit?) and this shows an example how to do so.

```js
$('form.benchmark-question-binary')
  .on("change validate", 'input[type="radio"][name="yesno"]', function(event) {
    let thisform = $(event.delegateTarget);
    let radios = thisform.find('input[type="radio"][name="yesno"]');
    let rChecked = radios.filter(":checked");
    console.log(radios.length > rChecked.length);
    console.log(radios.length, rChecked.length)
  })
  // now trigger the first one on startup
  .find('input[type="radio"][name="yesno"]').first().trigger('validate');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="benchmark-question-title">
  Am I the hero?
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <form class="benchmark-question-binary">
      <label class="benchmark-yes-no"><input type="radio" name="yesno"  value="yes" required>Yes</label>
      <label class="benchmark-yes-no"><input type="radio" name="yesno" value="no" checked required>No</label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <span class="benchmark-move-forward italic">If yes, move on to the next movement</span>
  </div>
</div>
```