# Check if radio button in a group has been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of grouped radio buttons, each radio button in a group has an attribute name like this : `page-x-layout` where `x` is variable.

My html code looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to do is to check if a radio button is checked in each of those groups.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried? What problem(s) have you encountered? Please show your code.

Comment: How has this been upvoted so much, it is off topic as it is way too broad as can be seen by the multitude of answers below

Answer (score 2):

You could map all inputs from rows to array and then use `every` to check if each row has checked input.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  var check = $('.row').map(function(e) {
    return $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')
  }).get()

  console.log(check.every(e => e == true))
})
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-1-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-1-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-1-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-1-layout">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-2-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-2-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-2-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-2-layout">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-3-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-3-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-3-layout">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-3-layout">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it helps!

```
$('#element').click(function() { 
  if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) {
       alert("it's checked"); }
    });
```

Comment: This won't work in my case, since it will always alert that message if I only selected one radio button in one group

Comment: You wanted check that only right?? You wanted an alert message every time a radio button is checked from one group!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$("input[name='html_elements']:checked").val()) {
  alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
```

[Using JQuery to check if no radio button in a group has been checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072249/using-jquery-to-check-if-no-radio-button-in-a-group-has-been-checked)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event to and get the current input ID and value by using `$(this)`

```
$('[type~="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    alert("ID = " + $(this).attr('id').split(' ') + "  Value =" +$(this).val() ); 

    });
```

```js
$('[type~="radio"]').on('change', function() {
  alert("ID = " + $(this).attr('id').split(' ') + "  Value =" +$(this).val() ); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
</div>
```

or if you need all values on load use `.each()` to get all

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $allradio = '';
  $('[type~="radio"]').each(function() {
  $allradio = $allradio + "ID = " + $(this).attr('id').split(' ') + "  Value =" +$(this).val()+'\n';
  });
  alert($allradio);
  $('[type~="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    alert("ID = " + $(this).attr('id').split(' ') + "  Value =" +$(this).val() ); 

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-1-layout">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-2-layout">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-1-page-3" type="radio" value="1" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-2-page-3" type="radio" value="2" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-3-page-3" type="radio" value="3" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="layout-4-page-3" type="radio" value="4" name="page-3-layout">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will only when I check some radio button, I want to know if the radio buttons are checked or name based on their name, since I want to check if these radio buttons are checked even if the user hasn't checked anything

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for each Radiobutton:

```
  if(document.getElementById('page-x-layout').checked) {
      //do something if radio button is checked
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say that this won't work, since `x` in `page-x-layout` is always variable so in html you could find `page-1-layout` and `page-44-layout` ...